# Using partial functions to model Set in Scala, e.g. type alias: Set = Int => Boolean

Tags: scala, type-alias

I'm trying to understand how type alias works and by extension, how a simple `Set` type modeled on `type Set = Int => Boolean` would be rewritten as a class with partial functions.

Background: I understand that I can create a type alias like above, and use it as a simple functional set data type:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (x => s(x) || t(x))
def contains(s: Set, n: Int): Boolean = s(n)
val s1 = Set(3)
val s2 = Set(7)
val u1 = union(s1, s2)
contains(u1, 3)                // res4: Boolean = true
```

All well and good. Takes some thinking but I get how it works; `u1`
essentially becomes a partial function based on:

```
union(s: (Int => Boolean), t: (Int => Boolean)): Int => Boolean
```

So if I wanted to turn this into a class, my first attempt would be something like this:

```
case class Set(v: Int) {
    def apply(i: Int) = i == v
    def contains(n: Int): Boolean = this(n)
    def union(n: Set): Set = (x => n(x) || apply(x))  // Missing param
}
```

But that doesn't work (the definition of `union` has a compile error, `x` is a missing parameter).

After fiddling with this for a while, I'm stumped on how to go about implementing a similar type without resorting to a more imperative approach (like actually creating a collection-based Set class). There must be a way to do this in a purely functional way...

Comment: I don't see a way to achieve what you want without resorting to OO. The problem with `union` is that it should be a Set, but it's defined as a function. To make it into a Set we'd need to have a extended instance of a Set where apply would be satisfied any of the sets, pretty much defeating the point of a implementation based on functions.

Comment: Type aliases work just by substitution.

Comment: I think that you have 3 Set definitions in your scope, lol... xD 1. Your type alias `Set`(function), 2. val s1 = Set(3) (`scala.Set`) 3. your `case class Set`. Not surprising it doesn't work... And no, union is not a partial function.

Comment: Also, this is a task from (FP in Scala)[https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1] so we shouldn't answer it according to https://learner.coursera.help/hc/en-us/articles/209818863-Coursera-Honor-Code.

Comment: The above are two different (e.g. not to be compiled together) chunks of code. Also this is a topic introduced in the Programming Scala book that I am trying to understand more thoroughly... and yes, re-introduced in Odersky's class, which I already graduated from with 100% so... no, not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `Int => Boolean`, not `Int`. So

```
case class Set(f: Int => Boolean) {
  def apply(i: Int) = f(i)
  def union(s: Set) = Set(x => this(x) || s(x))
  // or Set(union(f, s.f)) to use existing definition of union
}
```

For your own definition of `Set`, `apply` makes it a single-element set, so it isn't surprising you can't define `union`: union of two single-element sets can have more than one element.

Scala has separate namespaces for values and types. `type Set` or `class Set` define only the *type* `Set`, while `val Set`, `object Set` or `var Set` define a value, and `case class` defines both. Now, `Set(3)` needs a *value* called `Set`; in your first code sample there is no such value, so it uses the one from `scala.Predef`, which is imported automatically. `scala.Predef.Set(3)` returns a `scala.collection.Set[Int]`, which happens to extend `Int => Boolean`, which is why `union(s1, s2)` compiles. `case class` defines both a type *and* a value; so with above code `Set(3)` doesn't compile because this value is used instead of `scala.Predef.Set`.

Comment: This is very interesting – hadn't thought about wrapping `Int => Boolean` – however, it doesn't get to the desired endpoint, which is an API similar to the type alias-based API. That is, being able to `val s1 = Set(3)` and `s1.union(s2)` for instance.

Comment: If you want to write `val s1 = Set(3)`, you just need to define `def apply(i: Int)` in `object Set`. Note that in your first piece of code `Set(3)` uses `scala.collection.Set`, not the one you defined! `union` works only because the standard `Set[A]` extends `A => Boolean`.

Comment: I've added a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Ahh! Gadzooks. No wonder I've been getting such strange results. Yes, changing to "CSet" and now things are making more sense. Thank you, this is the information I've been missing -- and explains why it behaves the way it does. Much appreciated.